# Laravel 5: mkdir/Filesystem::makeDirectory with permissions from config

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, mkdir

I'm running into an issue this morning with `FileSystem::makeDirectory` which directly calls `mkdir`. I'm trying to create a directory recursively pulling the desired mode out of my config like so:

```
$filesystem->makeDirectory($path, config('permissions.directory'), true);
```

**config/permissions.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'directory' => env('PERMISSIONS_DIRECTORY', 0755),
    'file' => env('PERMISSIONS_FILE', 0644)
];
```

**.env**

```
...
PERMISSIONS_DIRECTORY=0775
PERMISSIONS_FILE=0664
```

When this is called, the directory is created but the permissions it gets are messed up. It gets something along the lines of `dr----Sr-t+`. After some research I've come to the conclusion that when I'm passing the value to the mode parameter from my config using `config('permissions.directory')` the mode is being treated as decimal rather than an octal. So the call to config is likely returning `775` which is being passed into the function, rather than `0775`.

If I remove the call to `config`, the directory is created with the correct permissions:

```
    $filesystem->makeDirectory($path, 0775, true);
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get around this while still being able to store my permissions on my config file?

Comment: Try the `intval` function: `intval('0755', 8)`

Comment: That seems to work perfectly, thanks. I'll accept if you create an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because permissions should be in octal, not in decimal. When you type `0755` as number - it is in octal format. When you are trying to use string `"0755"` - it will be auto converted to decimal `755`. And `755 != 0755`.

So, for correctly converting of string to octal number, you should use the `intval` function:

```
$permissions = intval( config('permissions.directory'), 8 );
$filesystem->makeDirectory($path, $permissions, true);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: Also, one more variant, but I'm not sure. Did you try to type `0755` instead of `"0755"` directly in the config? I think this should also work

Comment: If you notice, I have 0775 etc. in my config file and in my `.env` file. I managed to find that the issue only happens when it uses values retrieved from my `.env` file. The values end up in a string along the way and it ends up being cast to an integer when I'm passing it to `makeDirectory`. If I remove the values from the `.env` file it works.

Comment: So yeah in response to your question, yes I literally have `0775`, in my config file like in my question. That works if I don't have the value in the `.env`

Comment: Ah, yes, yes, it's `.env`, not old-style `local/*.php` config, just forgot about it :)

Comment: Good Answer!, It's great help, friend.